# My code for finding factorial is not working. Please somebody find the error

Tags: java

Here is my code:

It is not working for greater numbers to find factorial using recursion

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{   

 static String fib(int f)
{
    if(f!=1)
     return ""+(f*(Integer.parseInt(fib(f-1))));
    else 
     return "1";
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{

    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int f= sc.nextInt();
    int a[]=new int[f];
    int i;
        for( i=0;i<f;i++)
       a[i]=sc.nextInt();

    for( i=0;i<f;i++)
    System.out.println(fib(a[i]));
}

}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Be aware that the factorial grows very large and may exceed integer range very easily. Use doubles instead. Also, your code might just run very slow. And why do you return strings? Just return the number as is!

Comment: how large the number you are trying to achieve? also its all about storage and logic of implementation while generating factorial for large numbers

Comment: I'm not getting right output for number as large as 50 . It is working fine for smaller numbers. I'm returning String because factorials can be very large and the output could go beyond the range of int or long.

Comment: It doesn’t really help using `String` when next thing you do `Integer.parseInt(fib(f-1))`, trying to convert the `String` to an `int`, which will fail because the number is too big for an int.

Comment: Your code displays `0` for `0!` which is wrong. `0! = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem of the range of the type integer (2147483647). If you just replace int with long (range 9223372036854775807) like this

```
import java.util.*;

class Main
{   
    static String fib(long f)
    {
        if(f!=1)
            return ""+(f*(Long.parseLong(fib(f-1))));
        else 
            return "1";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int f = sc.nextInt();
        long a[] = new long[f];
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i<f; i++)
            a[i] = sc.nextLong();
        for(i = 0; i<f; i++)
            System.out.println(fib(a[i]));
    }
}
```

then the program can already calculate everything under 21!. But if you use double then it should work with higher numbers, because double has a range of 1.7976931348623157E308. With double the max working factorial calculation is 170!.

PS: I'm German so if i wrote incorrect english i'm sorry

Answer (score -2):

There is no error in the logic of your code. Since you use `int`, whose range is shorter than the factorial of numbers beyond `25`, you get faulty output. Instead, use `long` or, more preferably, `BigInteger`.

**NOTE:** You have to ***import*** the `java.math` package that contains the `BigInteger` class to use this type.

```
static BigInteger fib(BigInteger f) {
    if (!f.equals(BigInteger.ONE))
        return f.multiply(fib(f.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
    else
        return BigInteger.ONE;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int f = sc.nextInt();
    int a[] = new int[f];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < f; i++)
        a[i] = sc.nextInt();

    for (i = 0; i < f; i++)
        System.out.println(fib(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(a[i]))));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot for the solution sir!! Could you please also help me in finding out the error in the code I mentioned.

Comment: There is no error in the code. Just calculate the factorial of large number and compare it with the `int primitive size` you will get to know that you cant fit in large numbers greater than `int primitive size` in `int` primitive.
`int range is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`

Comment: Some one has downvoted my answer , It will be good if you explain the reason behind downvoting .

Comment: It will good if you suggest better things then coming and downvoting my answer.